# Refreshing page does not refresh profile data

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I've noticed that when I leave my profile page open on meta one day and access it the next day, I have to refresh the page twice, before it refreshes the profile data. And its the same results even with hard refresh <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. So, when I first access the page that had been left running all night, it looks like this:

[image]

Then I hard refresh the page and the only difference I see is some of the data graying out:

[image]

When I do the hard refresh the second time is when the *seen* and the *visited* values are refreshed:

[image]

I thought that doing a hard refresh would always refresh the page. Is this a bug or as per designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some messing around I think that's what happening:

1. When you visit any page in specific site (profile page is just like any other page) the "last active timestamp" is updated to the current date and time.
2. The "last seen" value is calculated **before** assigning the above timestamp, so it takes the previous time you were active and calculates the time difference between that time and the current time.
3. The "last seen" is not live and when calculated, being cached for about 10 minutes so if you just keep refreshing the profile page, you won't see it change every minute.

The last step is not really relevant to your case, but still something closely related.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> tells your browser to reload the page from the web instead of reloading it from it's (browser's) cache.

However, the server that you are requesting the page from can use some caching too to balance the load. This is what happens a lot on SO, pretty much everything here is heavily cached. So yes, you are refreshing the page, but the server gives you a cached copy still. Just give it some time.