# Does the 'last seen' count include self-views?

Tags: discussion

On the main profile page, it shows Last time viewed, and for a low-rep user like me, I am pretty much the only one who views my profile page, but the last viewed always has low times. I was wondering if the counter only updates when someone else views the page, or if you view it yourself

Comment: Refresh the page. Has it changed?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155021/refreshing-page-does-not-refresh-profile-data/155024#155024

Comment: Also, the counter only updates when somebody new views your profile. If somebody who has visited it before views it again, the counter doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't the time of the last time you viewed your profile page. It is the last time you were browsing the site. Self views of your own profile do contribute towards that in my experience, but due to caching it may take a while to show.

Comment: I know this answer has been "accepted", but is the answer based only on your experience **or** do you know for a fact that's how it works?  I've wondered the same thing myself.

Comment: @BellevueBob I spent several hours testing this a while back, but it is still in my experience, and I states so. I'm reasonably sure its right, but if someone from the SE team could confirm or deny, I wouldn't mind.